# vncviewer on windows connecting to linux box

Tags: windows, firefox, vnc-viewer

I'm just starting to use vncviewer and I'm having a problem resizing windows on the client side. For example firefox defaults to a small window and I can't resize it. I have tried the following. First of all server startup:

```
vncserver :6 -geometry 1024x768 &
```

1. for xterms this works but the font is too small and I can't change that:

   ```
   xterm -geometry 160x50
   ```
2. for firefox this doesn't work:

   ```
   firefox -height xx -width yy
   ```

   the window remains too small and anchored top/left

So, how do I get firefox to be larger?

thanks,
Paul.

**Update:**

The particular linux box seems to have a pretty barebones install and a lot of utilities are missing so I just tried a few different things and this worked for firefox:

firefox -safe-mode

I'm not sure what's causing the problem but in safe mode the browser window is pretty close to fullscreen so that will work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `xterm` you also want to take a look at the `-fn` option.  In a running `xterm` you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> plus the right mouse button to get a font menu.

Firefox appears to have not bothered with any useful options.  You might be able to use something like [wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) after the fact.